# How to switch from error track back to success track in railway-oriented program in F#?

Tags: f#

Using AsyncResult from Scott Wlashin and wondering how I can change from the error track to the success track.

Pseudo-code:

```
let orchestratorFunction() : AsyncResult<Customer, CustomerError> = asyncResult {

   let! output1 = callFunction1 arg1 arg2 |> AsyncResult.MapError CustomerError.Val1

   let! output2 = callFunction2 arg1 arg2 |> AsyncResult.MapError CustomerError.Val2

   let! output3 = callFunction3 arg1 arg2 |> AsyncResult.MapError (fun e -> ********HERE I WANT TO GET BACK TO THE SUCCESS PATH AND RETURN output3*********)

}

or a more realistic example: 

let createCustomer() : AsyncResult<Customer, CustomerError> = asyncResult {

   let! customerDto = mapDtoFromHttpRequest arg1 arg2 |> AsyncResult.MapError CustomerError.Val1

   let! validatedCustomer = validateCustomer arg1 arg2 |> AsyncResult.MapError CustomerError.Val2

   let! validatedCustomer = insertCustomer arg1 arg2 
      |> AsyncResult.MapError (fun e -> 
            match e with 
            | DuplicateCustomer _ -> 
                loadCustomerById xx 
                |> (fun c -> 
                      if c.LastCausationId = validatedCustomer.LastCausationId 
then c 
else e))
}
```

So basically I am trying to get out of the unhappy path, because this is an idempotent REST operation and any repetitive requests will be answered with 200 OK, as if they were the original request, so that the client can have a simple logic.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do using a concrete realistic example? It is hard to understand this in abstract terms and it seems likely that there is an easier way to do what you need. I also do not understand how you could return `output3` if the call to `callFunction3` failed?

Comment: As Tomas said, if the call to `callFunction3` failed, then you do not have a `Customer` instance, you have a `CustomerError` instance. You want to "get back to the success path", which means returning a `Customer` instance. **What will its value be?** How will you calculate it?

Comment: Sorry for the abstract example. The real example is in the context of REST API and Idempotency. A new Create Transaction request is accepted, then an insert is attempted into the database (e.g. this could be callFunction3). If the error from the database function is "Duplicate record" or similar, in the mapError I want to fetch the existing record, compare it with the newly-to-be-inserted record and if check is OK (X-Request-ID = LastCausationId) then I want to return back 200 OK with the record fetched from the database, so that this retry or the whole operation is idempotent.

Comment: You are right, in the mapError I will calculate and return a Customer record, so it will match the orchestrator function signature for the Ok path.

Comment: It seems to me that you're after the `catch` function. See an example here: http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/abstraction-monad.html#Examplesas I'm not sure if your `AsyncResult` has `catch` already implemented, but technically `catch` is the same as `bind` but for the error side of the DU.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from @Gus to this question ([AsyncResult and handling rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284040/asyncresult-and-handling-rollback)) it seems that bindError is what I needed. I created a similar to his bindError bindExn, and it seems to work as well, so now both error and exns can be converted to Ok:

(From Gus):

```
/// Apply a monadic function to an AsyncResult error  
let bindError (f: 'a -> AsyncResult<'b,'c>) (xAsyncResult : AsyncResult<_, _>) :AsyncResult<_,_> = async {
    let! xResult = xAsyncResult 
    match xResult with
    | Ok x -> return Ok x
    | Error err -> return! f err
}
```

(My code):

```
let bindExn
    (f: exn -> AsyncResult<'a,'b>)
    (xAsyncResult:AsyncResult<_,_>)
    : AsyncResult<'a,'b>
    =
    async {
        let! res =
            xAsyncResult
            |> Async.Catch
            |> Async.map(function
                | Choice1Of2 res -> res |> AsyncResult.ofResult
                | Choice2Of2 (ex:exn) ->
                    f ex
            )
        return! res
    }
```